# C# overload with override

Tags: c#, overloading, overriding

I can surely answer to this question by myself writing a dummy test but I want to know what people think about the question. Here it is:

Which method will be call when we have both at the same time overloading and overriding? I am only considering Type overloading and not arity overloading and when Type the overload are related.

Let me throw you an example:

```
class AA {}
class BB : AA {}

class A {
    public virtual void methodA(AA anAA) { Console.Write("A:methodA(AA) called"); }
    public virtual void methodA(BB aBB) { Console.Write("A:methodA(BB) called"); }
}

class B : A {
    public override void methodA(AA anAA) { Console.Write("B:methodA(AA) called"); }
}

new B().methodA(new BB());     // Case 1
new B().methodA(new AA());     // Case 2
new B().methodA((AA)new BB()); // Case 3
```

Can you tell what will happen in case 1, 2, and 3?

I personally think that overloadaing is evil and that there is no consistent thinking that could lead to a predictable answer. And that is completely base on a convention implemented in the compiler+vm.

EDIT: If you have some doubt about why overload is evil you can read the blog post from [Gilad Brach](http://gbracha.blogspot.ch/2009/09/systemic-overload.html)

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Overridden methods are excluded from method set when compiler determines which method to call. See [member lookup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691331%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) algorithm. So, when you call `methodA` on type `B`, set of members with name `methodA` from type `B` and it's base type will be constructed:

```
override B.methodA(AA)
virtual A.methodA(AA)
virtual A.methodA(BB)
```

Then members with `ovveride` modifier removed from set:

```
virtual A.methodA(AA)
virtual A.methodA(BB)
```

This group of methods is the result of lookup. After that [overload resolution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691340%28VS.71%29.aspx) applied to define which member to invoke.

1. `A.methodA(BB)` is invoked, because its argument matches parameter.
2. `A.methodA(AA)` will be chosen, but it is virtual method, so actually call goes to `B.method(AA)`
3. Same as option 2

Comment: you mean JIT compiler, don't you?

Comment: No, I don't mean JIT compiler. If you don't have appropriate method to call, you'll have compile-time error.

Answer (score 6):

No, it is entirely predictable. The method signature is resolved first - that is, the **overload** is determined first. Then, the most **overridden** method is called. So the output will be:

- A:methodA(BB) called
- B:methodA(AA) called
- B:methodA(AA) called

The method taking an instance of AA will be called in the second two cases, because this is the type of the reference that is passed in, and it is B's version that is called. Note that even this would produce the same result:

```
A instance = new B();
instance.methodA((AA)new BB()); // Case 3
```

Comment: I didn't mean that the code is unpredictable. Let me clarify it. In this example the compiler have to add 2 more axiom in the language. First overload is apply before override. It could have been in the other-way round and that would be totally acceptable. Second axiom dynamic type is used for override method lookup. And I can add a third axiom. Static type is used for overload lookup. All the axiom I have site are not predictable. Any other language could have choose a totally different set of axiom.

Comment: The compiler resolves the method signature in any strongly typed language. That has to come first. The overriding is handled by a Callvirt IL op code, which runs whatever version of that method is in the object in question at the time. Because the compiler doesn't know what that object is going to be, this has to be handled later. I disagree. The order has to be the way round it is in C#, Java etc...

Comment: I rather use the term "compile time" or "run time" as there are more precise than "later time". But assuming that "later time" is run time what you are describing is the classic  method lookup that you can found in any OO language (CLOS, Simula,  Smalltalk were those who invented this concept). But what i am saying is that the override could have been apply before so that you end up with callvirt IL in all 3 cases. Only a `new A().methodA(new BB())` would  call the "A:methodA(BB)" method. There is no semantic reason why one way and not the other way.

Answer (score 0):

I think the result will be this

case 1 : Console.Write("A:methodA(BB) called");

case 2 : Console.Write("B:methodA(AA) called");

case 3 : Console.Write("B:methodA(AA) called");

in case 3 it will look the type that it's passed, and it's B