# Strange better function member behavior

Tags: c#, .net

There is next code:

```
class Base
{
    public virtual void Sum(int a) { Console.WriteLine("Base A: {0}", a); }
}

class Exp : Base
{
    public override void Sum(int a) { Console.WriteLine("Exp A: {0}", a); }

    public void Sum(double a) { Console.WriteLine("Exp D: {0}", a); }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int a = 100;
    Exp b = new Exp();
    b.Sum(a);
    ((Base)b).Sum(a);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

It will print out:

Exp D: 100

Exp A: 100

Question is why is 'Exp D' in first line??
In C# language specification there is chapter '**1.50.3.1 Applicable function member**' and according it Sum(int) is *applicable function member* for call b.Sum(a).

According to chapter '**1.50.3.2 Better function member**' Sum(int) is *better function member* than Sum(double) (there is implicit conversion from int to double, while in first case no conversion at all).
What is going on?

Comment: *"Overridden methods are excluded from method set when compiler determines which method to call. "* - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10851731/1997232).

Comment: For more on this issue, see https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2007/09/04/future-breaking-changes-part-three/ and https://ericlippert.com/2013/12/23/closer-is-better/. The problem we face is: declaration site D is better than declaration site B, but int is better than double. C# says that "D is better than B" is *more important* than "int is better that double", so that's the winner.